# How to use condensed typewriter with latin modern and doc

Tags: fonts, typewriter, latin-modern, dtx

I'm documenting a class with (ltx)doc. The macro names are quite long so I get a lot of overfull hboxes.

AFAIK latin modern has an additional typewriter font which is condensed. How do I switch the `doc` package to use that? I'd prefer a solution for pdflatex.

Comment: As far as I can see it, the condensed typewriter font only comes in a light weight, which does not mix well with LMRoman in the medium weight.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write this in the preamble of your document

```
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{lmttc}{\hyphenchar \font-1 }
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmttc}{m}{n}
     {<-> ec-lmtlc10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmttc}{m}{it}
     {<->sub*lmttc/m/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmttc}{m}{sl}
     {<-> ec-lmtlco10}{}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmttc}
```

If you need OT1-encoding, change all `T1` into `OT1` and `ec-` into `rm-`.

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX one can say

```
\setmonofont[HyphenChar=None]{Latin Modern Mono Light Cond}
```

and get the same result (loading **fontspec**, of course).

Comment: Thanks. Bonus question: How to do this with xelatex/lualatex?

Comment: What did I win? :)

Comment: @egreg: Another upvote. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Incidentally, you can see the effect of this in the paper I gave at Practical TeX 2006 on document classes: http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-1/tb88flynn.pdf